# How teamcity builds project and requirements of msdeploy on client machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

Just want to know whether msbuild is built in teamcity or teamcity uses the installed msbuild.exe on your build machine. I have no visual studio installed on my build machine. Little bit confused as where to locate msbuild.exe on machine if no visual studio installed. 
Also requirements of msdeploy on client machine. Plz clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeamCity does not provide the compilers for any language, just the integration support to bring those tools together. For MSBuild specifically, [you'll need the .NET framework installed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/02/25/getting-started-with-msbuild.aspx), or Visual Studio:

> MSBuild ships as part of the .NET Framework, starting with v2.0 in Visual Studio 2005 and updated in v3.5 with Visual Studio 2008.

Alternatively, [you can make use of the Mono support that TeamCity provides](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Mono+Support) to go down that road.